# iOS: Do you think it is possible to do "image detection" with ARKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, augmented-reality, arkit

I would like to do augmented reality with ARKit but I have check that it is possible with plane surfaces
Here: [ARKit example](https://github.com/markdaws/arkit-by-example)

But impossible to find the way to do it with a simple image for example like in this example:
[example1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6x6Aa9qLXE)
and:
[example2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF52DbWsVns)

I would like to upload an specific image, and when my future app will "scan it", it will lauch me some augmented reality.
So you have any github project, or tutorial on that subject? It should be very useful.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone mentioned it before deleting his message, it will be possible in next ios release (now in Beta) in ios 11.3.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience

Answer (score 1):

This is now available in ARKit 2.0. A few steps to it, but its fairly straight forward.

Here are a few available tutorials:

https://www.appcoda.com/arkit-image-recognition/

https://hackernoon.com/arkit-tutorial-image-recognition-and-virtual-content-transform-91484ceaf5d5